# Node.js example not working on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to begin the backend of a MEAN project I'm working in right now. It's a project for testing purposes, and Node is still in my TO-DO list.

So, I today wrote this simple server to have something to begin with, and at least being able to see my Angular page and begin to create a simple server-side API. The example can be seen in many websites:

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Well, the problem is quite simple: when I try to access to localhost/myproject, it just doesn't work. Happens the same for 127.0.0.1/myproject. The js file is in the same folder than the project folder, so I should be able to access this way if the server were working.

I looked for an already answered question and found one in which you have to deactivate a directive in Windows Firewall... but that directive doesn't exist in mine.

So, any help with this?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what does not work, what error messages you get.

Comment: @Zerok try hitting localhost:8080/myproject

Comment: I'm not getting any message errors. The page just doesn't load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add port `8080` to your access url `127.0.0.1:8080/myproject.`

Comment: Hey, now it works! How can I modify my server so I can access to my project folder? Now it just shows the path I'm willing to access.

Comment: @Zerok, what do mean `access to my project folder?`

Comment: if I write for example: localhost:8080/myproject, I get a message saying "It Works!! Path Hit: /myproject", instead of actually accessing to the page.

Comment: @Zerok, Wow, in your response function `function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}`, there is no render page to response in it. I think maybe you should read some sample projects of `MEAN` for more details.

Comment: Can you please explain what this means to add a port to your access url?